# Enumeration of GADTs in Haskell

Tags: haskell, combinatorics, gadt

Could you please tell me are there any extensions of Haskell deriving mechanism for Enum class? I mean there are a lot of reasonable situations besides ``nullary constructors'' case. Are there any works on this topic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you really need GADTs? Or do you merely want to lift the restriction to a plain enumeration type with only nullary constructors? If the latter, then there are options. One is to use GHC's `Generic` mechanism together with an implementation of a suitably generic enumeration class. This is available in the `generic-deriving` package. Here is an example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
import Generics.Deriving

data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) (Tree a)
  deriving (Show, Generic)

instance GEnum Bool
instance GEnum a => GEnum (Tree a)

test :: [Tree Bool]
test = take 10 genum
```

Now, `test` is the following list:

```
[ Leaf False
, Node (Leaf False) (Leaf False)
, Leaf True
, Node (Leaf False) (Node (Leaf False) (Leaf False))
, Node (Node (Leaf False) (Leaf False)) (Leaf False)
, Node (Leaf False) (Leaf True)
, Node (Node (Leaf False) (Leaf False)) (Node (Leaf False) (Leaf False))
, Node (Leaf True) (Leaf False),Node (Leaf False) (Node (Leaf False) (Node (Leaf False) (Leaf False)))
, Node (Node (Leaf False) (Leaf False)) (Leaf True)
]
```

This implementation of `genum` uses diagonalization to merge products. This guarantees that every value actually appears somewhere in the list, but may lead to a surprising order in turn.

Comment: Oh, that's  what I was thinking of. Thank you.